# Update uitextView from another controller

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I want to update `uitextview` from another uiviewcontroller classes.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly clear what you are asking, but I think you mean that you want to send a message to a UITextView instance within another UIViewController subclass.

So long as this UITextView is a member of this UIViewController, you can send messages to it. (Of course, it must be declared as a property for getters and setters).

Example:

```
OtherViewController *otherViewController = [[OtherViewController alloc] init];
[[otherViewController textView] setText:@"your text here"];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:otherViewController animated:YES];
```

I suppose this could be useful if you were about to switch push or pop a view controller and needed to add information to it before you did so. Hopefully this answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can update your textview's text using NSNotificationCenter from other viewcontroller.